# Extract the list of MBeans registered against a Domain in JMX using Jython

Tags: tomcat, jboss, jython, jmx, mbeans

I am able to get Attribute info if I know the name of an MBean, but the application I am trying to monitor generates randomly named MBeans and therefore need to be able to query JMX for the list of MBeans registered in a Domain.

Here is an example of the view in JConsole, and what I am trying to pick up dynamically.

[image: JConsole Screenshot]

Below is the code that I have written and this is able to pull attributes, domains registered, but I can not seem to get out the actual list of MBeans in a domain.

```
    import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
    import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
    import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
    import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

    import sys, cmd, socket, optparse
    from urlparse import urljoin
    from cmd import Cmd

    def get_connection(host, port):
        serviceURL = str()
        serviceURL = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://"
        serviceURL = serviceURL + host + ":" + str(port) + "/jmxrmi"

        url =  javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL(serviceURL);
        connector = javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
        global remote
        remote = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();


    def get_domain_list():
        domainList = []
        get_connection('dt2apps2102', 8004)
        domainList = remote.getDomains()
        return domainList

    def print_domain_list():
        domainList = get_domain_list()
        for element in domainList:
            print element

    def get_domain_objects(domain):
        pass

    def get_object_list():
        dmiDomains = {}
        domainList = get_domain_list()
        for element in domainList:
            if element in ('SystemJobControl', 'MediaStore', 'fabric'):
                dmiDomains[element] = None
        return dmiDomains

    def get_attribute(domain, mbean, attribute):
        obn = javax.management.ObjectName(domain + ':' + 'name=' + mbean)
        return remote.getAttribute(obn, attribute)

    print get_object_list()
    get_object_list()
```

Comment: print get_attribute('SystemJobControl', 'listeners', 'ListenerEventsProcessed')

>>> 294L

Answer (score 10):

This should give you all names of objects:

`remote.queryNames(new ObjectName(domain + ":*"), null)`

And this will get the actual MBeans:

`remote.queryMBeans(new ObjectName(domain + ":*"), null)`